# Vanishing set equals set of rational points of quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $ Z(f) = \{ (a,b) \in \mathbb{C}^2\mid f(a,b) = 0, f(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y] \}$ and that $m_p = (x-a,y-b) $ is a rational point and is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

I want to show that the set $Z(f)$ is equivalent with the set of rational points of $\mathbb{C}[x,y] / \langle f\rangle$.

If $(a,b) \in Z(f) $ then $f(a,b) = 0$. An element in $\mathbb{C}[x,y] / \langle f\rangle$ is of the form $g(x,y) + p(x,y)f(x,y) $. I don't know how to connect the two things.

For example, if $(a,b) \notin Z(f)$, then it can still be a rational point of the quotient ring? Something tells me it's a hint it is a maximal ideal. How do I proceed?

Best regards

Comment: Hint: Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the words "rational points," or in this case probably "$\mathbb{C}$-rational points." or far more commonly "$\mathbb{C}$-points." In that case the $\mathbb{C}$-points of the $\mathbb{C}$-variety $X=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(f))$ are
by definition the following set
$$
X(\mathbb{C})=\hom_{\mathbb{C}-\mathrm{varieties}}(\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}),X)=
\hom_{\mathbb{C}-\mathrm{algebras}}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(f), \mathbb{C}).
$$
Now, such maps are rings are exactly given by specifying $x\mapsto a$, $y\mapsto b$ such that $f(a,b)=0$.